# Another Viewport Meta Tag Issue

Tags: ipad, viewport, css

Ahhh... I'm beginning to tire of the viewport tag.

Anyway, hopefully someone out there can assist with this question. I know similar questions have been asked on SO, and I've read quite a few of them, but they seem to be under different circumstances.

I have a DIV that is 100%x100%.

I've applied background-size:cover to the background image inside this div.

When testing in all browsers, I get a nice, pretty, full-screen background image that sizes with the browser window - as it should. Even on the ipad it will pull up and look great, in both orientations. :) Happy.

Now, as soon as I add the ridiculous viewport meta tag (which I'm foreseeing a lot of users slapping onto their websites alongside my script), the ipad revolts, unless it's exactly this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

As soon as I allow scaling of the page by changing the initial-scale or maximum-scale, the background-size cover breaks.

Any ideas?
Also, would it be a bad move to just remove the viewport meta tag in the script to avoid all of this together?
Thanks!

Comment: Why is the bg image not on the body? Is that not possible?